# Omegle-like application - How can I do it?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do an omegle-like application which is basically connecting two devices somehow so they can communicate with eachother.

I ran through some solutions, for example the Socket solution (Client - Server) and I even implementd it just to find out that it doesn't work if the devices don't share the same network (my bad, I don't have a lot of knowledge about these matters).

The other way I thought about implementing it would be the two devices constantly checking a row in my "Conversations" table on my database (on my server) through an API to see if there's new messages. So when someone send a message it would update that conversation row. But this solution seem to be a little complicated for what seems to be a simple problem and besides it seems to be kinda heavy to have an AsyncTask checking everytime for a change in the database.

So I would like to ask you guys if there's a "standard way" to do this, or a simplier way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing which I can think of (not sure if this is the best and correct way to do it) is to create `Client-Server` communication using `Sockets`. Using this type of communication your server will store the messages from (let's call it) `First User`. After that your server send notification via `Push-Notifications` to `Second User` and the application reads it and notify the user. So you can some basic system like this :

```
FirstUser  ---- (send message) ---> WebServer
WebServer   ---- (push notification)  ---> SecondUser

SecondUser ---- (send message) ---> WebServer
WebServer ---- (push notification) ----> FirstUser
```

So in this situation the work is done by your server side, application will only send and receive data from the backend. As far as I think this is the best way, please correct me if I'm wrong!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man. I don't know a lot about Sockets. As I said I implemented a first solution in which one device opened a serverSocket and the other one connected to it. But it didn't work when the devices where in different networks (e.g. home wi-fi and 3g). So this solution of yours wouldn't have the same problem? Thanks again

Comment: Connection between Server-Client doesn't rely on same network, so it will work no matter how far are the devices and what kind of connection are they using. You are connection to your server and actually he is doing the heavy work, not the application.

Comment: Hummm I got it. Reserching a little more I find out you are right. Using this system with GCM is the "right" way to do it. Thanks for the answer!